# Create bucket items from external database

Tags: sitecore-client, migration

We are migrating our legacy application in sitecore. We have a large database that we want to reuse in our sitecore application specially dbo.Product table. Product table contains ProductName, ProductID and other foreign key references. We are using buckets for Product creation in sitecore, I want to create all the Products from external database with existing fields(ProductID, ProductName etc) and apply corresponding renderings.There are many child items under each product. What is the best approach to solve this puzzle?

Product Structure :[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Can you expand on your question to make it clearer? For example, what do you mean by 'There are many child items under each product'?

Comment: Do you just want to expose your products from your current database in Sitecore? If so you don't actually need to import them as such. There are ways to pull the products in as items as if they exist in Sitecore - even though they actually don't. Are you able to maintain the existing database or do you need to get rid of it? If so this might be an option for you. As Martin says we'd need to see more info on your current data structure to help recommend the best approach.

Comment: I don't want to maintain my existing database. We want to create products in sitecore database.

Comment: @MartinDavies Suppose we have Product named AA then childs of this Product AA is bb, cc, dd and bb have further childs bb1, bb2 etc.

Comment: Child items in a bucket structure don't work very well as there is no easy way of getting to them. You would have to use something like the Express SubItem module: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Express_Subitem.aspx

Comment: Consider using the Data Exchange Framework.

Comment: From your illustration it is not clear if you have a lot of children under a single item, or just a deep content tree (with many descendants). If you do not have any items in your product structure with more than 100 direct children (i.e. not children's children), I do not believe that buckets are required.

Comment: There are around 3000 products.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to perform the import or are you asking how you can keep the parent/child relationship between the products and their sub-items?

Comment: I want to read data from external database and create all the products and their childs under Products bucket as shown in question.

Comment: Use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions. Write script in which you will connect your database and the use SPE to create hierarchical structure of items. Here is the link to the module: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx

Comment: What are the children of the product? Another products? Comments and opinions added by users? Anything other? Is the parent/child relationship important?

Comment: Children's are product related information like frequently asked question about product , news letters, services etc

Comment: In other words I want to create 3000 items reading fields value from external database and create items in sitecore tree programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would discourage you from copying your items into bucket in this case. According to Sitecore's documentation:

> When you store items in an item bucket, the parent-to-child relationship between the items is removed, and instead the items are organized in a folder structure according to the date and time they were created. Therefore, the item buckets feature is primarily designed for storing content items that do not need to be stored in a hierarchy.

Your description of a problem states that you do have an important parent-to-child relationshipt. In such a case I would recommend one of the two possible solutions:

1. If you have small number of products (I assume 3k is number of all the items including FAQs, newsletters, etc.) you can easily go with importing them as regular items
2. If you plan to have larger database of products you could add only the products into a bucket and other items (FAQs, newsletters, etc.) as regular items under a separate item and connect them using for example multilist.

Does this approach solves your problem?

Comment: I am using branch template in order to create child items.

Answer (score 0):

To import the items you could for example create a script using a bit of C# combined with the Sitecore Powershell module. Or you could do it purely in Powershell if you can extract the current data into a CSV. The module comes with a bunch of examples to get you started.

If you want to import the data into a products bucket but still retain the relationship between the product and the child items, then you need to remember to [lock the relationship](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/lock_a_parentchild_relationship) at the template level.